# Unable to start emulator on Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

I am unable to start my emulator on Android Studio 2.2 and getting the following error:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>
> Output:
>
> Hax is enabled
>
> init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
>
> Hax ram_size 0x40000000
>
> getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
>
> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>
> Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
>
> Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
>
> audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
>
> qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
>
> emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
>
> emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
>
> emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu
>   off' to disable it.

Getting same error in the console of AVD. I am trying to run with this following configurations :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ij7.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to AVD Manager.
2. Edit your AVD.
3. Select 'Graphics' to 'Software GLES2.0' option on 'Emulated Performance'.(Because some users did not install graphic video card drivers.)
4. Click Finish (Save).
5. Start AVD again.